# How to customize year format in a date format using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to get the following format using moment.js

```
Thu, 10 Oct 16, 2:00PM
```

The closest format I found using moment.js is using the following function.

```
moment(dateVar).format('llll')
```

where dataVar is the required date object.The output looks as follows

```
Thu, Oct 16, 2016 12:00 AM
```

I could not find any way to customise this date format or get the required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the moment docs you should be able to get your result by passing the following formatting string:

```
moment(dateVar).format('ddd, DD MMM YY, H:mmA');
```

I think this string should get you the desired result.
If I run it with the current date it returns this:

```
moment(new Date()).format('ddd, DD MMM YY, H:mmA');
//"Wed, 02 Nov 16, 10:25AM"
```

And extensive list of your display options with formatting strings is here:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 0):

See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

What you need is

```
ddd, D MMM YY, h:mmA
```

ddd - Day of week
D -Day of month
etc